# How to join two tables in a single sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables in a single database..
(1) user_details_home
(2) user_details_car
(3) users
 and i want to select data from two tables in a single query.. Following is the snippet of how i want to select data from these two tables(`user_details_home` and `user_details_car`) in a single `$query`

```
$query = "SELECT `users`.`email`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`last_login`, `user_details_home`.*
          FROM `users`, `user_details_home`
          WHERE `users`.`user_id` = :id
          AND `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_home`.`user_id`";
```

**and**

```
$query = "SELECT `users`.`email`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`last_login`, `user_details_car`.*
          FROM `users`, `user_details_car`
          WHERE `users`.`user_id` = :id
          AND `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_car`.`user_id`";
```

*so eventually i can perform this query*

```
$result = $this->db->select($query, array( 'id' => $this->userId ));
```

Thanks in advanced!

Here's the table structures
[user_details_home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMtxx.png)
[user_details_car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4gd.png)

Image is just a demo structure

Here is the complete path to my problem

---

//(1)

---

```
public function getAll() {
    $query = "SELECT `as_users`.`email`, `as_users`.`username`,`as_users`.`last_login`, `as_user_details`.*
                FROM `as_users`, `as_user_details`
                WHERE `as_users`.`user_id` = :id
                AND `as_users`.`user_id` = `as_user_details`.`user_id`";

    $result = $this->db->select($query, array( 'id' => $this->userId ));

    if ( count ( $result ) > 0 )
        return $result[0];
    else
        return null;
}
```

---

(2)     this code returns in AsAjax.php as :(Ajax)

---

```
switch ($action) {
case "getUserDetails":
    onlyAdmin();

    $user = new ASUser($_POST['userId']);
    echo json_encode( $user->getAll() );
    break;
}
```

---

(3)    then this case works as action in another user.js file as:(Below is the Javascript file)

---

```
users.displayInfo = function (userId) {
var username    = $("#modal-username"),
    email       = $("#modal-email"),
    firstName   = $("#modal-first-name"),
    lastName    = $("#modal-last-name"),
    address     = $("#modal-address"),
    age         = $("#modal-age"),
    phone       = $("#modal-phone"),
    last_login  = $("#modal-last-login"),
    ajaxLoading = $("#ajax-loading"),
    detailsBody = $("#details-body"),
    modal       = $("#modal-user-details");
```

//display modal
   modal.modal('show');

// set username (title of modal window) to loading...
   username.text($_lang.loading);

//display ajax loading gif
   ajaxLoading.show();

//hide details body
   detailsBody.hide();

$.ajax({
       url: "ASEngine/ASAjax.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {
           action: "getUserDetails",
           userId: userId
       },
       success: function (result) {
           //parse result as JSON
           var res = JSON.parse(result);

```
       //update modal fields
       username .text(res.username);
       email    .text(res.email);
       firstName.text(res.first_name);
       lastName .text(res.last_name);
       address  .text(res.address);
       age      .text(res.age);
       phone    .text(res.phone);
       last_login.text(res.last_login);

       //hide ajax loading
       ajaxLoading.hide();

       //display user info
       detailsBody.show();
   }
```

});

};

---

(4)     and at last information comes by pressing a button:

---

```
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                     onclick="users.displayInfo(<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>);">
                      <i class="icon-pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                      <?php echo ASLang::get('details'); ?>
                  </a>


    <div class="modal" id="modal-user-details" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-username">
                <?php echo ASLang::get('loading'); ?>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="details-body">
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('email'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('email'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-email"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('first_name'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('first_name'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-first-name"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('last_name'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('last_name'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-last-name"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('address'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('address'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-address"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('age'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('age'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-age"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('phone'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('phone'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-phone"></dd>
                <dt title="<?php echo ASLang::get('last_login'); ?>"><?php echo ASLang::get('last_login'); ?></dt>
                <dd id="modal-last-login"></dd>
              </dl>
            </div>
              <div align="center" id="ajax-loading"><img src="assets/img/ajax_loader.gif" /></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <?php echo ASLang::get('ok'); ?>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

basically, function getAll() is linked to getUserDetails in second step, then getUserDetails is linked to user.displayInfo in third step, and user.displayInfo linked in fourth step. So all i have to do it to perform two $queries as one.
          I hope this would help!

Comment: use union all for this

Comment: email, username, last login columns are in user tables u dont want these?? because other two those u need not have these column i hope

Comment: Hi @devpro, thanks..but i am having difficulties in union because there multiple records in query..Can you please take some time and show me the updated code. I would reallly appreciate that.

Comment: `UNION` is intended to aggregate multiple records from two or more queries.

Comment: you need to join these two user_details_home and user_details_car???? and dont want to userid, username, email lastlogin from user table???

Comment: Please add the table structures (no need for column types just column names)

Comment: I need that info from users tables...username, email and last_login all three

Comment: This can be done in a single query, I would need the table structures because it is required when using alias and joins

Comment: U don't need a union for that, just combine the two queries in to one.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details_home` (
  `id_user_details` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user_details`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: hello @filiprem,devpro,axel amthor, thanks for your precious time, but your codes didn't work for me,

Comment: @PrakashNakrani: tell me your expected result...

Comment: Hi @devpro, i have updated my question, hope it would help you to figure out the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$query = "
SELECT user_details_car.first_name,user_details_car.phone,user_details_car.address,
user_details_home.first_name,user_details_home.phone,user_details_home.address
FROM user_details_car, user_details_home
WHERE user_details_car.user_id = user_details_home.user_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `user_details_home` and `user_details_car` have identical structure (same column names, same column order, same data types), you can use this:

```
SELECT users.email, users.username, users.last_login, user_details_home.*
FROM users, user_details_home
WHERE users.user_id = :id
AND users.user_id = user_details_home.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT users.email, users.username,users.last_login, user_details_car.*
FROM users, user_details_car
WHERE users.user_id = :id
AND users.user_id = user_details_car.user_id
```

This does not weed out duplicates. Please specify more details (data structure & requirements) if you need a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Combining both should look like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`email`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`last_login`, `user_details_home`.*, `user_details_car`.*
          FROM `users`, `user_details_home`,`user_details_car`
          WHERE `users`.`user_id` = :id
          AND `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_home`.`user_id`
          AND `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_car`.`user_id`;
```

**Caveat**: This will only return rows, if user has a car *and* a home.

Better approach with `left join`:

```
SELECT `users`.`email`, `users`.`username`,`users`.`last_login`, `user_details_home`.*, `user_details_car`.*
          FROM `users`
          LEFT JOIN `user_details_home` ON `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_home`.`user_id`
          LEFT JOIN `user_details_car` ON AND `users`.`user_id` = `user_details_car`.`user_id`
          WHERE `users`.`user_id` = :id;
```

Probably the `*` maybe incorrect syntax and you have to list the columns explicitly (what anyway is better for performance), I didn't test that.